# Giving unique names to GDB logging files in a script

Tags: automation, gdb

I would like to log GDB command output to a log file.

This is done using the following command:

```
set logging file outfulfile.txt
```

But, instead of simple `outfulfile.txt`, I would like to give a unique name to the file; for example `outfulfile-PID.txt`. This is because I will have several processes simultaneously producing the output and I want each one to log to its own unique file.

How can I programmatically derive such a file name in a GDB script?

Answer (score 1):

There area few ways.

One relatively simple way is to use gdb's "eval" command.  It substitutes arguments like printf, and then executes the result as a gdb command.  This is a new-ish command.

If you don't have "eval" you might still have Python scripting.  In this case you can write a short (one line) Python script like:

```
(gdb) python gdb.execute('set logging file ' + .. your logic here ..)
```

If you don't have Python scripting, then your gdb is really old and you ought to upgrade.  However you can still maybe accomplish what you want, just with some awful gyrations using "shell" and writing out a script that you then "source" back into gdb.  Though this technique seems somewhat hard in this case.